# cd two levels down from root

Tags: zsh, directory, cd-command

I'm a web developer (Drupal mainly). When I develop websites I do so within a /workspace folder.

So I have folders like this.

```
/workspace/project/
/workspace/project/sites/default/files/
/workspace/project1/
/workspace/project1/sites/all/modules/contrib/date
```

I would like to have a command which takes me to my project root, which is always

```
/workspace/something/
```

So that when I am in:

```
/workspace/project/sites/default/files/
```

[specialcdcommand] will take me to:

```
/workspace/project/
```

But when I am in:

```
/workspace/project1/sites/default/files/
```

[specialcdcommand] will take me to:

```
/workspace/project1/
```

At the moment I tend to do this:

```
cd /workspace/p[tab]
```

... which is not good because I sometimes land in a different project version without noticing.

I use zsh.

Comment: you can probably work something up with `pwd` and `cut` or `awk` and and them `PATH` I think a oneliner is even possible

Comment: An alternative I use is to bind `ALT + ,` to `cd ..`. `function widget-cd-up() { cd ..; zle reset-prompt; }; zle -N widget-cd-up; bindkey -v '^[,' widget-cd-up`. Even if I'm in the middle of typing a command, I can just `ALT + ,` as many times as I want (the `^[` is a literal escape char).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
specialcdcommand() cd ${(M)PWD#/*/*/}
```

Or:

```
specialcdcommand() cd ${${(M)PWD#/*/*/}:?Not deep enough}
```

or:

```
specialcdcommand() cd "${(M)PWD#/*/*/}"
```

to avoid going to your home directory if you're not already over two levels down.

In `zsh`, the `(M)` variable expansion flag changes the  behaviour of the `${var#pattern}` operator so the the **M**atched string is expanded instead of being removed. `:?` is the standard/Bourne operator to return an error (and cancel the command) if a variable expands to an empty string. Note that `zsh` is the only shell that has a consistent way of nesting parameter expansions.

POSIXly:

```
specialcdcommand() {
  p=${PWD#/*/*/}
  [ "$p" = "$PWD" ] || cd "${PWD%"$p"}"
}
```

Or to avoid clobbering the `$p` variable:

```
specialcdcommand() {
  set -- "${PWD#/*/*/}"
  [ "$1" = "$PWD" ] || cd "${PWD%"$p"}"
}
```

Comment: Nice POSIX solution! Is it actually required to quote the expansion of `$p` within the parameter expansion of `"${PWD%"$p"}"`? I see "[e]nclosing the full parameter expansion string in double-quotes shall not cause the following four varieties of pattern characters to be quoted, whereas quoting characters within the braces shall have this effect" in POSIX 2004, but I think that only refers to hardcoded pattern matching, if I'm reading correctly. Is the behaviour when encountering a pattern inside an unquoted variable unspecified?

Comment: @ChrisDown, yes it's needed except in `zsh` where pattern matching on variable is not implicit except in `sh` emulation. `"${PWD#$p}"` (`${PWD#$~p}` in `zsh`) is `"$PWD"` with the leading part matching the $p pattern removed. `"${PWD#"$p"}"` (or `${PWD#$p}` in zsh) is `"$PWD"` with a the content of `$p` removed from the start. Try with `p='*/*'`

Answer (score 2):

This will change directory to the second outermost directory (it should work in any POSIX shell as long as file and directory names don't contain newline characters):

```
descend() {
    IFS=/ read -r x root project x << EOF
$PWD
EOF
    cd "/${root:+$root/$project}"
}
```

It works by splitting the (first line of the) path into its components, taking out the root and project names, and putting them back together.

If you needed to extend this indefinitely, you could use the (non-portable) `-a` switch to `read`, which creates an array.

Comment: `<<<` works fine in bash or zsh, but is not supported in more basic POSIX shells like `dash`. `pwd|read` will always work.

Comment: @michas, `pwd|read` will work (except that it will stop at the first newline character), but `read` is not guaranteed (by POSIX) not to run in a subshell (in `zsh` it does not though).

Answer (score 1):

First you have to ensure you're in a project directory.
I suggest you this function :

```
function cdproot (){
    CURRENT=`pwd`
    [[ $CURRENT == /workspace/* ]] && echo "Going to project home.." || ( echo "Not in a project subfolder" ; return 1 )
    PROOT=`echo $CURRENT | awk -F\/ '{print "/"$2"/"$3}'`
    cd "$PROOT" && return 0;
}
```

Please add it to you `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: This will break if the resultant directory contains characters from `$IFS`.

Comment: @ChrisDown, it will not. Give me an opposite example please.

Comment: Does zsh uses bashrc file ?

Comment: @Kiwy No ! in this case it has to be added to `~/.zshrc` file of course ! the question doesn't specify the shell used so i supposed BASH as default :-)

Comment: @Slyx Well, at the time of my comment, it would. Your edit rectifies it somewhat, but still fails for directories that contain multiple consecutive instances of characters from `$IFS`.

Comment: @ChrisDown yes for your first remark but still need an example to confirm a such failure probability.

Comment: @ChrisDown, zsh does not do word splitting upon variable expansion implicitly. (you need `$=CURRENT` to ask for word splitting). `zsh` echo expands escape sequences like `\n`, `\e`... though, so `echo` should not be used here.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
cd "/`pwd|cut -d"/" -f2,3`"
```

create a script and include this line inside.
The quotes allow to use space or tab in file name.
<strike>It will not work with folder containing space.</strike>

You can integrate it to your `.zshrc` profile file like this:

```
function prjroot(){
    cd "/`pwd|cut -d"/" -f2,3`" && return 0;
}
```

Also if your in a primary level like `/opt` `/usr` it will not do anything.

Comment: This will break if your directory name contains any character in `$IFS`.

Comment: what is `$IFS` ? I'm curious about that.

Comment: as we speak of `zsh` I think the name of variable is different. because I can't find it in man zsh. But well, my test does work so fat even with space.

Comment: It's the internal field separator, see `man zshparam`.

Comment: I guess adding quotes should do the trick no ? @ChrisDown